# How to store a value greater than "999" in double while using parseDouble function?

Tags: java, android

I am not able to store value greater than "999" while using parseDouble function. This is my code:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

double amount = Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(balanceAmt.getText().toString())));
```

It is only storing value upto "999" not greater than that. It does not allow me to store value "1000" or greater.

Error message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123,456.78"
```

Comment: show the code for the formatter,

Comment: double could go up to 1.7*10^308... please show your code :)

Comment: Why are you parsing, then formatting, then parsing again? This seems like too much work to me.

Comment: most likely he is limiting the string length in the formatter, example System.out.println("double : " + String.format("%.2f", input)); double input = 32.123456;

Comment: NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

Comment: formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

Comment: formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

Comment: Please write your solution in "Answer" instead of commenting here so that everyone else can also notice your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default method NumberFormat.format(String) automatically puts a comma separating thousands when setting it to formatted text. This comma can not be parsed into a double datatype because it only accepts '.' as the decimal split character and numbers around it.

This can be seen by this test:

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble("1000")).replace(",", ""));
```

If the number requires a comma then use the .replace() method to replace it when parsing it to a double. Otherwise use a custom instantiation for your Number formatter such as:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000.00");
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123,456.78"

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1000"

Comment: This might be a problem coming from the formatter then, could you upload the code to that in your question?

Comment: NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Highly appreciable.

Comment: Happy to help, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am working under the assumption that `balanceAmt.getText().toString()` is returning `123,456.78` or similar.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

double amount = Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(balanceAmy.getText().toString().replace(",", ""))).replace(",", "")); 

System.out.print(amount);
```

When you get the balance from balanceAmt, it has the comma, so you have to remove it. When if goes through the formatter, it re-adds the comma back, meaning you have to remove it again before the second `parseDouble` is done.

Comment: .replace(",", "")

Comment: Yes, `.replace(",","")` to remove the comma from the string being parsed and again to remove it after formatting.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer.